# Copy blobs between storage containers in different subscriptions in Azure using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation

Iam trying to copy blobs created in last 24 hours from one storage account to another storage account which are in different subscriptions using powershell. I wanted to automate this using Azure automation but facing issue while selecting the Subscription context. It allows me to select only one subscription context at any time and since the 'copy' points to different subscriptions, the script is failing. Any input is highly appreciated, below is my script.

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $AzureSubscriptionId1

# Get Source Storage Account

$SrcStorage = Get-AzStorageAccount -name $SrcStorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $SrcStorageAccountRG

Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $AzureSubscriptionId2

# Get Target Storage Account
$TgtStorage = Get-AzStorageAccount -name $TgtStorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $TgtStorageAccountRG

$Days = 1

Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $SrcStorageContainerName -Context $SrcStorage.Context | Where-Object { $_.LastModified.DateTime -gt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)) } |  Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -DestContainer $TgtStorageContainerName -DestContext $TgtStorage.Context
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the errors you’re getting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download `AzCopy` tool from microsoft website here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10
2. `AZCopy` supports data copy between local drives, azure blob, and even AWS.
3. `AZCopy` has below syntax:
   `azcopy copy [source] [destination] [flags]`
4. Login to AZCopy of the source location.

   `azcopy login`
5. Generate SAS token for the destination location (Make sure you give write permissions)
6. Run the command AZCopy (It's one command on a single line please)

   `azcopy cp "https://[source-account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]" "https://[destination-account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/directory]?[SAS]"`

Comment: Azcopy cannot be used in Azure Automation Runbooks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct my code. The issue was how I was referring to the Storage context and not because of multiple subscriptions. Here is the working code.

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $Subscription1

# Get Source Storage Account Context

$StorageAccountContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SrcStorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey 'ABC'

Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $Subscription2

# Get Target Storage Account Context

$TgtStorageAccountContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $TgtStorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey 'DEF'
$Days = 2


Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $SrcStorageContainerName -Context $StorageAccountContext | Where-Object { $_.LastModified.DateTime -gt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)) } |  Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -DestContainer $TgtStorageContainerName -DestContext $TgtStorageAccountContext -Force
```